# Is swapping variables by array destructuring efficient?

Tags: ecmascript-6, processing-efficiency

ES6 supports array destructuring which could be used to swap variables in succinct syntax like below, but is this efficient and suggested in performance sensitive code as array processing? Because it seems a new temporary array is needed to complete this operation.

```
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

Comment: You may get some info on evaluation [from the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-destructuring-assignment).

Comment: @Li357 The specification does not detail performance

Comment: @Bergi I was addressing the "it seems a new temporary array is needed to complete this operation" concern.

Answer (score 6):

Let's test !

```js
let a = 42
let b = 69

console.log("for 2000000 iterations");

console.time("deconstruct")
for(let i=2000000; i>=0; --i)
  [a, b] = [b, a];
console.timeEnd("deconstruct")

console.time("classical")
for(let i=2000000; i>=0; --i) {
  let tmp = a
  a = b
  b = tmp
}
console.timeEnd("classical")
```

So it not seems to be the better way to do so.

Comment: What results are you getting in which browser?

Comment: Ah ? It's works for me on Firefox 57 and Chrome; I get `for 2000000 iterations - deconstruct: 22.460ms - classical: 3.980ms - function: 1.580ms`. It's ES6 arrow function syntax in fact

Comment: Have you tried to actually swap two values with the "function" syntax? Sure it doesn't throw an error, but it does not have the expected result

Comment: Hum.. You're right, I did not expected this haha. Let's remove this case..

Comment: @NatNgs +1, Have you test other types like bool (takes 4 bytes), arrays & objects?, any difference you saw? If so much of difference, what is the point of its use? cost vs convenience.

Comment: I let you run the test by yourself and get your own conclusions :)