# How to understand this syntax? [a, b] = [b, a]?

Tags: javascript

In a sense, I know it is a syntax maybe from es6 that change the position of `a` and `b`,
but I wonder is it elegant to web fronted programmer? And is it necessary to replace intermediate variables like:

```
var a=3,b=5;
var temp;

temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

to this:

```
var a = 3,b = 5;
[a,b] = [b,a];
```

And what difference between them on performance?

Comment: MDN Docs on Destructuring assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Peroformance? figure it out by making a https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is swapping variables by array destructuring efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943709/is-swapping-variables-by-array-destructuring-efficient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid ways of swapping variables.

Destructuring requires less code and could be considered a more elegant approach, but it looks like it is currently slower than using a temp variable:

```js
const startTempVariable = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
  var a=3, b=5;
  var temp;
  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
console.log(`temp variable: ${new Date() - startTempVariable}ms`);

const startDestructuring = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
  var a=3, b=5;
  [a,b] = [b,a];
}
console.log(`destructuring: ${new Date() - startDestructuring}ms`);
```

Both approaches are quite fast, though, so for most web programming scenarios either approach would be fine.

If you are coding something for performance you would currently want to use a temp variable.